# Scrollbar issue with Kendo Window

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I am using kendo window. When I am not specifying any width to the kendo window, horizontal scrollbar  is coming in the browser window. The code is as below.

```
 window.kendoWindow({
        actions: [
          "Pin",
          "Minimize",
          "Maximize",
          "Close"
       ],
       position:{
          top:0,
          left:0
       },
       close: onClose,
});
```

Can anybody please explain why this is happening?
 Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to what you are doing ?

Comment: @bitsbuffer Please refer fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/49AXA/87/)

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in the control. I have logged it [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/3700). A possible workaround is to add this CSS to the page:

> ```
> .k-resize-ne,
> .k-resize-se,
> .k-resize-e {
>   right: 0;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, and I guess you'll have to ask Telerik regarding this

My guess - it's probably due to the css styling.

A workaround can be setting the width like this:

```
width:"99.6%"
```

This gets the window snugged nicely within the browser with no scrollbars.

I've edited your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49AXA/94/) with the width

Answer (score 0):

In forum Telerik suggest to call e.sender.destroy(); in deactivate event.
See https://www.telerik.com/forums/destroying-a-window-after-maximizing-breaks-page-scrolling?actionMode=replyPost&postId=3ec6ce5e-bbb9-43c4-8ddb-685a469cb90e

This didn't work for me.

My initial work-a-round:
Set width and height to almost 100% and center window.

Telerik suggested work-a-round until bugfix: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/3701) - this worked for me.